# how to set Main class path in Eclipse Oxygen for a Maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am not able to set Main class path in a maven project in Eclipse Oxygen.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify it in the `pom.xml` as described in

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37671717/927493